# Forcing ngSubmit in presence of [action] attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, ng-submit

What Angular says...

> [ngSubmit] prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.

So **if you were unable to remove the [action] attribute from HTML**, how would you override this behavior to inject custom code on form submittion and prevent the defined [action] to get triggered?

One possible solution is to create a directive and override the DOM property "onsubmit". The CONS here is you are forced to configure it on backend when you could reach the same using the angular attribute

```
    app.directive("contactForm", function(){

        return {
            link: function( scp, elm, att )
            {
                elm[0].onsubmit = function( evt )
                {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                /* your custom code here */
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. `ng-submit` provides you with a way to perform custom code instead of regular form submission. You just have to _not_ define an `action` attribute on the same `<form>`.

Comment: In the environment I'm working the form it's already created with an [action] attribute and I cannot remove it manually from HTML. It's weird I know, but it's what it is. I'm going to update OP. Thanks!

Comment: If you're able to add the `ng-submit` directive onto the element, how come you're unable to remove `action` attribute from it?

Comment: Haha good point. It's a web IDE called WebFlow, they let you handle custom attributes and even override the value for [action]. But you can't remove it, if you leave the attribute empty it will use their default action target for internal form system. http://oi60.tinypic.com/hv6yww.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove `action` before `ng-submit` gets compiled, just create a directive with a higher priority, that removes the attribute.

```
app.directive('remove-action', function () {
    return {
        priority: 1,    // ngSubmit has priority 0
        compile: function (element) {
            element.removeAttr('action');
            return function link () {};
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Wasn't aware of "priority". That seems good to me, I'm going to test it now. Thanks

Comment: May I ask why did you put the link function inside compiler and not as sibling?

Comment: [See documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) (`link` config is unused if `compile` is defined.)

Answer (score 0):

So I was having a similar problem and here is how I finally solved it.

For angularjs 1.2, it's enough to set action to blank

action = ''

For angularjs 1.3, you have to set action to something like this

action = 'javascript:;'

I am not sure if this is valid html, or best practices, but it does work.